# Show second selection if satisfied by the first selection after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to build a registration page. At some point the user must select his/her country. If the country has states then a second drop down menu with the states of that country should appear.

So far so good. Using jQuery i have accomplished it. The code is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //if JavaScript is enabled we need to hide the state HTML part
  $('p#state_nojs').hide();

  $('select#country').trigger("change");

});

$('select#country').change(function(){

    var country_selected = $('select#country option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: { country : country_selected }
            }).done(function(data){
                $("#states").html(data);

    });

});
```

The **data.php** is a script that takes the country selected as an argument, searches the database, and returns all states associated with it. The states drop down menu is then inserted inside the empty states div.

The problem starts when i press the submit button. They way i programmed it, is to keep the current user selection and input (sticky form) for all fields except password. So i did the same with country and state.

When the submit button is pressed, and there is an error during registration, the reloaded page  remembers the country selection but the states drop down menu is not be visible, even though the country selected has states.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The states are only added to the DOM when the select is changed.  If you wanted them to be shown based on the selected country be default as well, you'd need to do that and have your `.change()` event handler.

Comment: So i will need to perform 2 ajax calls? One to test whether the country selected has states and the other to show the states associated?